# uWSGI Fastrouter – How to change the routing weight after it has been set?

Tags: python, uwsgi

I'm using [uWSGI](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) to serve a Python web app. I support multiple instances by using a [FastRouter](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Fastrouter.html) + [SubscriptionServer](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/SubscriptionServer.html) frontend.

In this scenario, each instance registers to the FastRouter by using this method: http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Fastrouter.html#way-4-fastrouter-subscription-server

I would like to be able to change the weight (and ideally the keys as well) for existing mappings without having to interact with the instances themselves. Is there a way to do this?

**Update:** How can I *get* the current mappings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manage the subscription externally from the uWSGI instances simply sending raw udp packets.

This is an example: https://github.com/unbit/uwsgi/blob/master/contrib/subscribe.pl

Comment: Interesting... now I have only to make it work in python, my perl is a little rusty. I updated my question. :-)

Comment: for getting the current mappings just enable the fastrouter-stats-server, it exposes all off the entries (in addition to rotuer and domains stats)

Comment: Ok, I will try this and come back. In the meantime, this should be the Python version (untested): https://gist.github.com/GaretJax/7689247

Comment: yes it should work, just remember you can add other infos to 'payload' (like weight)

Comment: Everything works (getting and setting). The problem now is that the uWSGI instance keeps refreshing the subscription and resets the weight to its old value. It there a way to overcome this?

Comment: you can completely avoid sending subscription from instances and let your external system do it. Eventually you can add the 'check' keyval to --subscribe2. If the file specified by 'check' exists, subscriptions packet will not be sent (until it will be removed)

Comment: mmmh.. probably not what I want for my use case, but you replied more than extensively. Grazie Roberto.